# Is IDL 8.5 able to read tables with strings, dates and values in it?

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am very new in the IDL scene and I am struggling for hours with a problem and I hope you can help me:

So right now I am trying to read data from a table ("file.txt"). I would like, that every column is saved in a variable (I thought about using STRARR)

I found this tutorial: http://www.idlcoyote.com/tips/ascii_column_data.html

This is very useful, when you want to read **numbers** for every column, which works fine.
This is the table from the tutorial above:

**Tutorial table:**

```
Experiment 01-14-97-2b9c
No. of Data Rows: 5
Temperature         Pressure          Relative Humidity
  20.43             0.1654                 0.243
  16.48             0.2398                 0.254
  17.21             0.3985                 0.265
  18.40             0.1852                 0.236
  21.39             0.2998                 0.293
```

**Code:**

```
OPENR, lun, "tutorial.txt", /GET_LUN
header = STRARR(3)
READF, lun, header

data = FLTARR(3, 5)
READF, lun, data
temperature = data(0,*)

print, data
print, temperature
```

**Output data:**

```
  20.4300     0.165400     0.243000
  16.4800     0.239800     0.254000
  17.2100     0.398500     0.265000
  18.4000     0.185200     0.236000
  21.3900     0.299800     0.293000
```

**Output temperature:**

```
  20.4300
  16.4800
  17.2100
  18.4000
  21.3900
```

---

Looks quite good, for numbers. 
But what about when I have strings with dates, times, but also numbers in it, like this:

**My table:**

```
Experiment 01-14-97-2b9c
No. of Data Rows: 5
Date              Start time             End time             Value
12-Feb-2002       05:08:10               06:08:30             20
08-Mar-2002       07:35:38               09:25:59             100
20-Jun-2002       12:30:35               16:15:18             5536
25-Jul-2002       04:02:06               07:02:58             5822
02-Aug-2002       23:30:25               23:55:22             456
```

The code above won't work anymore. When I am using this `my_var= data(0,*)`, the whole data will be saved in variable `my_var`, of course because the data are no more looking as columns, but in a whole row.

FLTARR is setting this data

```
12-Feb-2002       05:08:10               06:08:30             20
```

to this result (of course because of **FLT**arr)

```
12.0000
5.00000
6.00000
20.0000
```

And STRARR is saving the data good in `my_var`, but without separating the columns.

**What I want:**

I would like to have every column in one variable, so that I can handle these variable data later in another code.

```
dates = data(0,*)
starts = data(1,*)
ends = data(2,*)
values = data(3,*)

print, starts
```

**Output:**
Start time

```
05:08:10
07:35:38
12:30:35
04:02:06
23:30:25
```

(and also the rest of my variables)

I hope you can help here.
Maybe I misunderstood something, if so please let me know it.

For any other suggestion or solution I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use `STRSPLIT` in some manner, either each line as you read it or all at the end.

Here is an example of doing it all at the end. First, read the data into a `data` array (ignoring the `header` array):

```
IDL> openr, lun, 'file.txt', /get_lun
IDL> header = strarr(3)
IDL> readf, lun, header
IDL> data = strarr(5)
IDL> readf, lun, data
IDL> free_lun, lun
```

Then split on whitespace:

```
IDL> tokens = strsplit(data, /extract)
```

And, finally, extract elements by position:

```
IDL> dates = (tokens.map(lambda(x: x[0]))).toarray()
IDL> starts = (tokens.map(lambda(x: x[1]))).toarray()
IDL> ends = (tokens.map(lambda(x: x[2]))).toarray()
IDL> values = (tokens.map(lambda(x: long(x[3])))).toarray()
```

You've got your values now:

```
IDL> help, dates, starts, ends, values
DATES           STRING    = Array[5]
STARTS          STRING    = Array[5]
ENDS            STRING    = Array[5]
VALUES          LONG      = Array[5]
IDL> print, values
          20         100        5536        5822         456
```

UPDATE: Make sure you have done

```
IDL> compile_opt strictarr
```

in scope before these commands.

UPDATE: To sort these arrays by `value`:

```
IDL> ind = sort(values)
IDL> values = values[ind]
IDL> dates = dates[ind]
IDL> starts = starts[ind]
IDL> ends = ends[ind]
```

Comment: Your solution looks quite good, but for some reason this error appears, when the map function it's been called:
**"Keyword MAP not allowed in call to: IDL_OBJECT::GETPROPERTY"**
Do you know why this error message is appearing?
I think the **strsplit** works, there are no white spaces. It looks like this:

`12-Feb-200205:08:1006:08:3020`
`08-Mar-200207:35:3809:25:59100`
`20-Jun-200212:30:3516:15:185536`
`25-Jul-200204:02:0607:02:585822`
`02-Aug-200223:30:2523:55:22456`

Comment: It's probably an IDL version issue. I'm not sure when map was added, but fairly recently. What version are you using?

Comment: My IDL version is 8.5, Build id: 20150707

Maybe it is also an issue of my OS. I am using Windows 10 right now.

Comment: Wow, with the command "**compile_opt strictarr**" it really worked now. But why does it work after the compile_opt?
Can you also put this **compile_opt strictarr** to your solution answer, so that other people can see it?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I also have one little question:
With this solution, do you know how to **sort** the list by the value of the column "value"? The other corresponding values must also follow the sorted "value" column. Is this right now even possible?

Comment: "compile_opt stricter" tells IDL to use only square brackets for indexing, parentheses are for calling functions. While this doesn't seem like the case here, it is generally good practice and makes the parsing simpler for IDL. I would recommend putting it in a startup file *and* including it in *every* routine you write.